# How to solve this system with logarithms?

Tags: equation-solving

I mean a symbolic solution of
$$\frac{\log \left(x^2+10
   x+25\right)}{\log
   (y-10)}+\frac{\log \left(y^2-20
   y+100\right)}{\log (x+5)}=4\land
   \frac{\log (2 x+9)}{\log
   (y-10)}+\frac{\log (23-2 y)}{\log
   (x+5)}=2$$
over the reals. The `Reduce` command fails with it:

```
Reduce[Log[x + 5, y^2 - 20 y + 100] + Log[y - 10, x^2 + 10 x + 25] == 4 && 
Log[x + 5, -2 y + 23] + Log[y - 10, 2 x + 9] == 2, {x,y}, Reals]
```

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

The `ContourPlot` command performs only one curve.

```
ContourPlot[{Log[x + 5, y^2 - 20 y + 100] + 
Log[y - 10, x^2 + 10 x + 25] == 4, Log[x + 5, -2 y + 23] + Log[y - 10, 2 x + 9] == 2},
{x, -4.5, 10}, {y, 10, 11.5}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Numerical commands fail too.

```
NSolve[Log[x + 5, y^2 - 20 y + 100] + Log[y - 10, x^2 + 10 x + 25] ==  4 && 
Log[x + 5, -2 y + 23] + Log[y - 10, 2 x + 9] == 2, {x, y}]
```

> NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.

```
FindRoot[Log[x + 5, y^2 - 20 y + 100] + 
Log[y - 10, x^2 + 10 x + 25] == 4 &&
Log[x + 5, -2 y + 23] + Log[y - 10, 2 x + 9] == 2, {{x, 5}, {y,10.5}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. 
>   {x -> -3.83392*10^101 - 1.89741*10^97 I, 
>    y -> 2.84399*10^101 - 1.92551*10^97 I}

Comment: `FindRoot[{one, two}, {{x, -3.9}, {y, 11.2}}]`delivers a result (one and two are your equations)

Comment: @mgamer: Thank you. It is useful.

Comment: An exact solution is $  \left\{ x=-{\frac{22}{5}},y={\frac{53}{5}} \right\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eqns = Log[x + 5, y^2 - 20 y + 100] + Log[y - 10, x^2 + 10 x + 25] == 4 && 
    Log[x + 5, -2 y + 23] + Log[y - 10, 2 x + 9] == 2 // Simplify;
```

Constrain the arguments of the logs to be positive

```
cons = And @@ Cases[eqns, Log[z_] :> z > 0, Infinity] // 
  Simplify[#, Element[{x, y}, Reals]] &

(* 10 < y < 23/2 && 9 + 2 x > 0 *)
```

`Simplify` the equations using these constraints

```
eqns2 = eqns // Simplify[#, cons] &;
```

The solution is then

```
sol = Solve[eqns2 && cons, {x, y}, Reals]

(* {{x -> -(22/5), y -> 53/5}} *)
```

Plotting

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[List @@ eqns2],
 {x, -9/2, -3}, {y, 10, 23/2},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{x, y} /. sol[[1]]]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To see the discontinuity at `x  ==  -4`

```
eqns2 /. x -> -4
```

[image]

And zoom in on the plot

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[List @@ eqns2],
 {x, -4.02, -3.98}, {y, 10.96, 11.04},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{x, y} /. sol[[1]]]}]
```

[image]

The discontinuity is a single point, i.e., a single pixel.

Comment: +1. Thank you. However, your plot shows one more solution. Am I not right? Can you kindly explain that?

Comment: No, when you zoom in you'll see a hole, see my plot in red rectangle.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: I don't see a hole in your picture. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't the Reduce command analyze the domains of the logarithms over the reals automatically?

Comment: It would be good if `Reduce` did; however, `Reduce` concluded that it could not solve the equations and reported that. `Reduce` did not provide an inaccurate result.

Answer (score 3):

We simply first equation as follow:

We have $\log \left(y^2-20 y+100\right)=2 \log (y-10)$  and

$\log \left(x^2+10x+25\right)=2\log \left(x+5\right)$

And so $\dfrac{\log (x+5)}{\log (y-10)}+\dfrac{\log (y-10)}{\log (x+5)}=2$

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{a}=2\Longrightarrow a^2-2ab+b^2=0\Longrightarrow(a-b)^2=0\Longrightarrow a=b$

$\Longrightarrow\log (x+5)=\log (y-10),\Longrightarrow y = x+15$

```
  Solve[{y == x+15,Log[2 x + 9]/Log[y - 10] + Log[23 - 2 y]/Log[x + 5] == 2}, 
{x,  y}, Reals]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{22}{5},y\to \frac{53}{5}\right\}\right\}$

```
ContourPlot[{y == x+15, 
  Log[23 - 2 y]/Log[5 + x] + Log[9 + 2 x]/Log[-10 + y] == 
   2}, {x, -4.9, -3}, {y, 10.1, 12}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Let's substitute first equation into second.

```
   Log[23 - 2 y]/Log[5 + x] + Log[9 + 2 x]/Log[-10 + y] == 2 /. 
  y -> x + 15 // FullSimplify
```

$\dfrac{\log (-2 x-7)+\log (2 x+9)}{\log (x+5)}=2$

$\log (-2 x-7)+\log (2 x+9)-2 \log (x+5)$

```
Plot[Log[-7 - 2 x] + Log[9 + 2 x] - 2 Log[5 + x], {x, -4.9, -3}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Solve[Log[-7 - 2 x] + Log[9 + 2 x] - 2 Log[5 + x] == 0, x]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{22}{5}\right\},\{x\to -4\}\right\}$

Note that $x=-4$ is NOT a solution of original problem since it makes denominator zero.

Alternatively we can use `FunctionDomain` without any restating equation.

```
 eq = { Log[x^2 + 10 x + 25]/Log[y - 10] + Log[y^2 - 20 y + 100]/Log[x + 5] - 4, 
   Log[2 x + 9]/Log[y - 10] + Log[23 - 2 y]/Log[x + 5] - 2};
dom = FunctionDomain[eq, {x, y}];
eq2 = And @@ Thread[eq == 0] && dom // FullSimplify;
Solve[eq2, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{22}{5},y\to \frac{53}{5}\right\}\right\}$

Or use `Reduce`

```
Reduce[eq2, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> x == -(22/5) && y == 53/5

Comment: Can you kindly base "Your problem can be restated as..."?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you.

Comment: Can you kindly ground  your statement "Your problem can be restated as..."?

Answer (score 2):

ContourPlot and simplified equations show you, you get into complexes for `x < -5 && y < 10` . 
Therefore `PowerExpand` under these conditions and Solve does a easy job.

```
eq2=eq//FullSimplify//PowerExpand[#, Assumptions->x>-5 && y>10] &
```

{ (2 Log[5 + x])/Log[-10 + y] + (2 Log[-10 + y])/Log[5 + x] == 4 &&

Log[23 - 2 y]/Log[5 + x] + Log[9 + 2 x]/Log[-10 + y] == 2   }

```
sol = Solve[eq2, {x, y}, Reals]
```

{    {{x -> -(22/5), y -> 53/5}}    }

Comment: Thank you. What are eq and eq2?