# Numerically solving a system of two equation, one containing a log function

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve those equations:

```
eqns = 
  -1796853 + 19321 x + 83018.53984692502` x (-8649 + x^2) + 
      39.56247732409712` x (-8649 + x^2)^2 + 
      0.005059047659697752` x (-8649 + x^2)^3 + 
      10.329634791516803` x ((1000 + 
            1.7850911998308758` y) Sqrt[-101.94940899999999` x^2 + \
(1000 + 1.7850911998308758` y)^2] - 
         101.94940899999999` x^2 Log[(
           0.09903931860948798` (1000 + 1.7850911998308758` y + 
              Sqrt[-101.94940899999999` x^2 + (1000 + 
                 1.7850911998308758` y)^2]))/x]) == 0 && 
    611524 y + 
      0.1205783688509235` (-101.94940899999999` x^2 + (1000 + 
           1.7850911998308758` y)^2)^(3/2) == 0 // Simplify;
```

I have already used some conditions to avoid for negative values inside the Log function as indicated on another post [How to solve this system with logarithms?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184381/how-to-solve-this-system-with-logarithms) but it did not work for my case:

```
cons = 
  And @@ Cases[eqns, Log[z_] :> z > 0, Infinity] // 
    Simplify[#, Element[{x, y}, Reals]] &

sol = NSolve[eqns && cons, {x, y}, Reals]
```

It just returns me the NSolve function without solving it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `NMinimize[Abs[expr1]+Abs[expr2],{x,y}]` finds a small minimum but `logargument/.solution` is negative. `NMinimize[{Abs[expr1]+Abs[expr2],logargument>0},{x,y}]` finds a huge minimum but `logargument/.solution` is positive. Is it possible there is no solution for positive logargument?

Comment: I'll investigate what you pointed out, maybe I made some mistake in deriving those eqs (physical solutions in the model I'm working with require for positive logargument). On the other hand I expect that NSolve response for the case of no solutions to be the empty set "{}". Thank you Bill.

Comment: Your "cons" defines a function, but it is used without argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`"]

eqns = -1796853 + 19321 x + 83018.53984692502` x (-8649 + x^2) + 
       39.56247732409712` x (-8649 + x^2)^2 + 
       0.005059047659697752` x (-8649 + x^2)^3 + 
       10.329634791516803` x ((1000 + 
             1.7850911998308758` y) Sqrt[-101.94940899999999` x^2 + \
(1000 + 1.7850911998308758` y)^2] - 
          101.94940899999999` x^2 Log[(0.09903931860948798` (1000 + 
                 1.7850911998308758` y + 
                 Sqrt[-101.94940899999999` x^2 + (1000 + 
                    1.7850911998308758` y)^2]))/x]) == 0 && 
     611524 y + 
       0.1205783688509235` (-101.94940899999999` x^2 + (1000 + 
              1.7850911998308758` y)^2)^(3/2) == 0 // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // Simplify;

ContourPlot[Evaluate[List @@ eqns], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -120, 40}]
```

[image]

```
sol = FindRoot[eqns, {x, 95}, {y, -10}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* {x -> 92.986023667945379060, y -> -5.9811971865340859795} *)

eqns /. sol

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention Bob.